# git: set temporary cache folder to avoid permissions error?

Tags: git, npm, npm-install, git-config

I'm running into a permissions error trying to npm install from my github repository.  I.e. when I run:

```
sudo npm install git+https://github.com/senseijames/ionic-app-scripts.git#master --unsafe-perm
```

I get the following error:

> npm ERR! code 1
>  npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone
>   --depth=1 -q -b master https://github.com/senseijames/ionic-app-scripts.git
>   /Users/admin/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-109fcd19
>  npm ERR!
>   /Users/admin/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-109fcd19/.git: Permission
>   denied

I'm already using nvm, and I've tried `umask` (to set the default permissions for new folders created within tmp/), `git clean`, as well as the [oft-recommended npm permissions fix](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) - no dice.

I'm hoping I can skirt the issue by changing the temporary cache folder that git uses (to one that I've already created, with open permissions).

Is there a way to set the temporary cache folder that git uses?  (Or another way around this silly problem?)

Comment: Don’t run npm with sudo.

Comment: Without sudo, I get a different permissions error (EACCES) earlier in the process (at which point the CLI recommends I 'run again as admin').

Comment: Can you show the full permission error when running without sudo?

Comment: The gist: **Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/admin/Documents/SeamGen/AmericaPharmacy/node_modules/.staging**

Full error: https://imgur.com/SUkCQ77

Comment: `sudo rm -r node_modules` and run `npm install` again, then `npm install git+…`, both without sudo.

Comment: Magical!  Thank you!